# Laravel: Strange Behaviour With Two 'orderBys'

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to use two orderBy's in order to filter items by their sort_order (i.e. 1, 2, etc.) and name.

I've attempted virtually every combination in terms of the position of the orderBys, ascending, and descending, etc.

Laravel:

```
$product_types = ProductType::orderBy('sort_order', 'desc')->orderBy('name, 'asc)->paginate($per_page);
```

Database Table:

[image: a busy cat]

Result:

[image: a busy cat]

I wish for 'Hardware' to be first as its sort_order is 1, 'Office Supplies' to be second as its sort_order is 2, and then everything else after to be in alphabetical order from a-z.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109120/how-does-order-by-field-in-mysql-work-internally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has problems with sorting NULL values, you could use one of this two solutions to archieve what you want:

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('ISNULL(sort_order), sort_order'), 'ASC')
```

or:

```
->orderByRaw('ISNULL(sort_order), sort_order ASC');
```

in order to get the NULL values last and then concatenate the `->orderBy('name'...)` as usual.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) function, it will return the first column that is not null. See:

```
$product_types = ProductType::orderBy(DB::raw("COALESCE(sort_order, name)"), "asc")
    ->paginate($per_page);
```